# how can i validate year textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using a textbox on my page which is used to enter year in `yyyy-yyyy` format.

Can you tell how can i validate textbox in this format through javascript??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you mean a range of years? eg (between) 1980-1993

Comment: @minikomi: not between 1980-1993..even i want to enter year like `1980-1999`

Comment: What @minikomi means is, whether you want to validate the format only (i.e. 4 digits dash 4 digits) or also the range of the years (e.g. the users are not allowed to enter a start date that is before 1975). We have to know that to be able to give you a correct answer.

Comment: @ Felix Kling: yes, i want to validate the format only (i.e. 4 digits dash 4 digits).

Comment: In which case, Merjin's answer should be fine... Be careful what you accept and how you want to use it though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match it with a regular expression:

`var pattern = /\d{4}-\d{4}/;`

Comment: Hmm.. but does year 0000 make sense? How about 9999? 
What to do in the case 2831-0134...

Comment: @minikomi - Merjin's RegExp is what the OP asked for. Of course it may not be what they want. :-)

Comment: Yep, just saw the new comment.. sorry!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using any javascript library (like jQuery, etc), [Javascript Regular Expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) could be used for validating the input.

Comment: Why would jQuery help or be an alternative to a regular expression?

Comment: It's not an alternative. But some of jQuery plugins could complement and simplify the pure regular expression approach.